# Complex JavaScript page to test browsers performance?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, safari, javascript, comparison

I have three different browsers I want to compare: Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, and Safari.

I don't need very sophisticated mechanism; it can simply open a webpage and render.

I tried Gmail, Google Docs, and others, but it seems like they do a great job on both, the web browser and the page because everything is under a second.

Does anyone have a link where I can test browser performance (not necessarily network band width or browser rendering, as in http://acid3.acidtests.org/)

I guess a page with tons of JavaScript is in order.

Do you have one?

**EDIT**

Heheh this is my attempt :P Obviously there should be a better way:

```
<script>
    //.... ahh forget it. 
</script>
<input type="button" value="Start" onClick="testIt();"/>
```

Comment: Did you try the experiments and tests I suggested 20 minutes ago? I would argue that they are the "better way" you seek ;) Hehe.

Comment: @Jonathan: They are inded. This is my ewok contribution to the site :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered the JavaScript benchmark sites?

- [SunSpider](http://www2.webkit.org/perf/sunspider-0.9/sunspider.html) (Hosted by WebKit)
- [V8 Benchmark Suite](http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/data/benchmarks/v5/run.html) (Hosted by Google) **[BROKEN LINK]**
- [Dromaeo](http://dromaeo.com/) (Hosted by Mozilla)

Answer (score 4):

Chrome also has some really neat "[experiments](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/)" you can test in various browsers.

- [Javascript Fireworks](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/js-fireworks/)
- [Depth of Field](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/depth-of-field/)
- [Canvas 3d Engine](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/canvas-3d-engine/)

To name a few.

Comment: Don't forget [WebGL](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl).

Answer (score 1):

[Peacekeeper](http://service.futuremark.com/peacekeeper/index.action) is a pretty good all-around test for each browser. You can see overall results from others as well.

Comment: Nice!!, really amusing test by the way